# Display rich text in the feed

Tags: case, richtextarea, casefeed, service

I have a question concerning the case feed. One of our requirements is to give engineers the option to post rich text messages in the feed. Messages should be in the feed (not a separate page) to give a complete story of the ticket.

After some research I found out that this is not supported using the post action. Does anyone know a workaround for this by any chance?

I got this far: 
Now I have a custom object which holds a rich text field and is linked to the case. When creation one this creation is displayed in the case feed. This give following result:

[image]

As u notice the rich text content is in the hover. Yet I don't seem to be able to display the field directly on the feed.

If anyone could help on this matter and tell me if it's possible to display this content directly in the feed it would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This feature has now been delivered...

...in Classic: [[Winter '16 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_chatter_feeds_rich_text.htm)]

...and in Lightning Experience: [[Spring '17 release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_chatter_lex_rte.htm)]